# mprotect API on OS X Tiger

Tags: c, macos, unix, mprotect, osx-tiger

I'm trying to use mprotect API on MacOSX 10.4 (tiger), I tried every possible way I know , it always returns -1, with errno 13, which means "permission denied" while I'm trying to add the write permission to some executable code.

The same code exactly works on MacOS X 10.5 (leopard).

the code is pretty simple

```
int ret = mprotect((void*)pFunc, 4096, PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
```

where pFunc is the address of any function loaded in the process address space. I tried to remove the PROT_EXEC before adding the PROT_WRITE access right, but no luck. I also tried aligning pFunc with the memory page size, no luck neither..

Any idea how to make this working?

Comment: +1 , I had the same exact problem and eventually just dropped OSX from my supported list.

Comment: Show the full program that produces a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is the memory you are trying to modify mmap'd from the executable?  The man page for mprotect (on Linux) seems to indicate that this would prevent you from modifying (PROT_WRITE) the memory location.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about OSX. That said, can you use the Mach function [vm_protect](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xholer/macosx/xnu/vm_protect.html)?

Comment: vm_protect is returning KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE, because the new protection increased the maximum protection beyond the existing maximum protection. I don't know how to change the "default" maximum protection?

Comment: by doing vmmap to may process, i see that the virtual memory page that contains pFunc has r-x maximum permission, while i see other executable virtual memory pages have rwx permission, any Idea how to change this for my executable pages? Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

You do not have permission to write into executable regions.  Anyway, why should you?

I'm sure this works on some platforms, but not all.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I do have the permission to write into executable regions on leopard (which is more secure,..etc). i'm trying to do something similar to what microsoft detours is doing on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea.  Try marking it EXEC without the WRITE.  I think denying write+exec may be a security feature.

To write to it then, mark it as WRITE but not EXEC.